# How to built nested Static side menu using accordian in angular2?

Tags: angular, accordion, angular2-directives, webpack-2

I have nested static side menu like this:

```
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Item1</a>
           <ul>
               <li>sub Item1</li>
               <li>sub Item2</li>
          </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Sub Item2</li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply accordian to this menu like If I click Item1 then sub Items Panel should open, If I click Item2 then Item1 panel should close and item2 panel should open.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

In above site examples are given only for normal menu, I did not get idea to follow up the code according to my requirment (want to apply accordion nested static side menu)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this one http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu maybe this one fulfill your needs.

Comment: here Menu is built in form of array, But I want to apply accordian for static menu